# Spring SAML Sample: SSOCircle SHA256 not supported

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I am trying the Spring SAML Sample project with SSOCircle and default keystore.
After importing the SP metadata into SSOCircle, the SSO worked correctly.

Now, I wanted to **change the encryption algorithm from SHA-1 to RSA SHA-256**. 
So I extended the SAMLBootstrap class as shown here:

```
public final class CustomSAMLBootstrap extends SAMLBootstrap {  

  @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
        config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
        config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);
    }
```

Also here is the extended metadata configuration

```
   <!-- Extended metadata properties -->
<bean id="extendedMetadataSP" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
    <property name="local" value="true"/>
    <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
    <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
    <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
    <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
    <property name="signMetadata" value="true" />
    <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="${entityBaseURL}/saml/discovery"/>
    <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="${entityBaseURL}/saml/login?disco=true"/>

</bean>
```

So I regenerated the metadata via the `org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator` bean and tried to re-upload the newly generated SP xml. Although SSOCircle will fail with **007 error code.**

[image]

At this point I am not sure if there is an **additional step** to complete for me in order to use sha256 on SSOCircle?

Can someone please help?

**EDIT:**

The problem I am having when uploading the metadata to SSOCircle I believe it has to do with the EntityDescriptor section where the signature algorith is specified as SHA256 as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#urn_com_apakgroup_bristol">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>mAT5iN6IWyTCQiPplFmOq4vu8SUzCBfpAC4XBOu2+eM=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>i6hH............bA==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDZTCCA............eVdvh</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

Changed signMetadata to false, unfortunately it does not make a difference.

```
<property name="signMetadata" value="false" />
```

SAML RESPONSE:

```
2016-09-13 15:03:06,786 DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil:115 - Computing signature over input using private key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA256withRSA
2016-09-13 15:03:06,802 DEBUG org.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil:123 - Computed signature: 8b4...dfa9
2016-09-13 15:03:06,802 DEBUG opensaml.saml2.binding.encoding.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder:251 - Generated digital signature value (base64-encoded) i0...==
2016-09-13 15:03:06,803 DEBUG PROTOCOL_MESSAGE:74 - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO" Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/publicidp" ForceAuthn="false" ID="ac8eeg2j9d932hh4fe90fa71844e00" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2016-09-13T14:03:06.775Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...[my-sp]...</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

2016-09-13 15:03:06,803 DEBUG opensaml.ws.message.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder:56 - Successfully encoded message.
2016-09-13 15:03:06,804 DEBUG springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage:93 - Storing message ac8eeg2j9d932hh4fe90fa71844e00 to session C17D8A94DED2F79BDD92CBF7A99462C6
2016-09-13 15:03:06,805  INFO springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger:127 - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;...[my-sp]...;https://idp.ssocircle.com;;;
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample request that leads to the error as well as the debug trace mentioned above?

Comment: I've created keystore with SHA256 and it worked. You might have problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error7 is that the signature of the meta data cannot be validated. This is described at the : [how-to section](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/idp-tips-tricks/ssocircle-how-to/) "Signed metadata might cause validation problems. We recommend removal of the signature as the fastest workaround."

You have meta data signature enabled:

```
<property name="signMetadata" value="true" />
```

turn it to "false".

Comment: Hi I did turn it to false, did not make any difference. Thanks for assisting anyway